# Can I specify that a type is an arbitrary record?

Tags: types, elm, row-polymorphism

I have a type

```
type alias WithStatus l =
  { l
  | status :
    Status
  }
```

This extends a record with a status field.

Now I'd like to make a function that takes a record and gives it a particular status, so I made:

```
addStatus : Status -> l -> WithStatus l
addStatus status l =
  { l
  | status =
    status
  }
```

However elm complains that `l` could potentially not be a record.

```
This is not a record, so it has no fields to update!

21|>  { l
22|   | status =
23|     status
24|   }

This `l` value is a:

    l

But I need a record!
```

Which is true.  However elm has no way of knowing that the `l` in the type alias is a record either, it checks for that on the use site.  So it seems a little odd that it's complaining here.

Is there a way to express a function which takes any *record* `l` and adds a status?

Comment: "This extends a record with a status field." To my understanding, this claim is incorrect. `WithStatus` matches any concrete record types that have the field `status`. But it doesn't introduce a new type on its own.

Comment: @viam0Zah I'm not sure how those two are distinct.  I can do `type alias Dummy = WithStatus {dummy:Bool}`, to get a record with exactly two fields, `status` and `dummy`.  I don't see how that is not extending `{dummy:Bool}` with an additional field.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to express a function which takes any record l and adds a status?

You can do

```
setStatus : Status -> WithStatus l -> WithStatus l
setStatus status l =
  { l | status = status }
```

which replaces an existing status, but the ability to introduce new fields in the way you were hoping isn't possible any more.

It used to be, [from 0.7](https://elm-lang.org/news/0.7) until 0.16 (released in 2015) where it was removed because [it wasn't felt to be actually all that useful](https://elm-lang.org/news/compilers-as-assistants):

> **Simplified Records**
>
> There is kind of a long story here. The short version is that record update uses a normal equals sign now, like this:
>
> ```
>      { point | x = 4 }
> ```
>
> Instead of using the backwards arrow <- like before. This was something that a lot of people got tripped up on, [even after they had a lot of experience](https://github.com/elm-lang/error-message-catalog/issues/16), so overall I think this will make things a bit friendlier. The backwards arrows also led to weird code texture when used within a case such that you have forwards and backwards arrows going everywhere.
>
> Okay, but the long story is interesting if you are into language design!
>
> Elm uses a very cool record system. It is based on [an excellent paper by Daan Leijen](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/65409/scopedlabels.pdf) that lets you add and remove fields from records, all while keeping the types simple. I really love this mix of power and simplicity!
>
> I added support for this back in 0.7, and at the time, I had never seen a language (with a real working compiler) that allowed field addition and deletion like this. So I had intuition, but no way to get real experience. I worried that it could encourage overly complex code, so from the start I was very conservative, knowing that we could expand or contract the features as we got more data.
>
> Well it has been more than two years since then, and the results are in. Pretty much no one ever used field addition or deletion. In the few cases where people did use it, it got pretty crazy pretty quickly. The one real-world case I know of is recorded [here](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues/985#issuecomment-121927230) if you want to see, and the code could be rewritten with custom types, which turned out nicer anyway.
>
> Removing addition and deletion will also make Elm easier to optimize (described more [here](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues/985)). This is especially true if we are targeting platforms besides JavaScript, but allows some simplifications in JS too. In fact, [the benchmarks we ran for 0.16](https://gist.github.com/evancz/76b619a83a6650a89918) show that this made record updates a lot faster!

Comment: The first link does not actually support the claim that this used to be possible.  It just shows that records could be extended.

Comment: Maybe you should re-read you own question, in particular the question posed on the last line: "Is there a way to express a function which takes any record l and adds a status?" In what way do I not answer that?

Comment: It shows that a specific record can be updated.  The core issue for me is an expressing an *arbitrary* record type.  As stated by the title "Can I specify that a type is an arbitrary record?"

Comment: No, the core issue is that you can't update arbitrary records, because you don't know anything about them. If you did, it wouldn't be arbitrary.

Comment: Btw, type annotations are entirely optional. If you want the infeasibility of what you're trying to do demonstrated more clearly, just remove the type annotation.

Comment: Even with the type annotations removed, it has to have a type, it doesn't simply become untyped.  To the best of my knowledge there was not a way to do this in 0.7, because the types would not allow it.

Comment: You say in your answer that it used to be possible, I pointed out that that claim is not actually shown by the link.  That is all, I don't know why you are being so hostile.

Comment: You're not acknowledging that the question has been answered, and instead focus on unimportant details. I'd be happy to correct this minor detail if that's the only thing you think is wrong, but not if I'm misinterpreting the question entirely.

Comment: I think there are two issues here: 1) is that the type error implies that the issue here is whether l is a record or defined as a custom type (or a built in type). There is now way to specify in the type system “record which may have some fields, but we don’t know what any of them are”, hence this can’t be solved. 2) Even if this type annotation was possible, the function still wouldn’t be possible to implement, since as @glennsl points out, there is (no longer) a way to add fields to records.